# CSS flex: 0 0 auto is creating a 1px gap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using `flex: 0 0 auto;` in CSS and on some browsers there is a 1px gap between the divs.

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: black;
}

.scrollWrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.scrollWrapper > * {
    background-color: white;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollWrapper">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

The issue only occurs when using Edge and Safari. On these browsers it looks like:

[image: blackLinesBetweenDivs]

Is there anything to fix this issue?

Comment: you could have used grid for this with less CSS to write `body {
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 100vh;
   background-color: black;
   margin:0; }.scrollWrapper {
 overflow-y: scroll;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 10vh;
   height: 100%; }
    .scrollWrapper > * {
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 3px green}`  -  for the gap, your browser is trying to round at screen  your 10% of 100% of 100vh to pixels because a pixel cannot be broken into pieces :) your lines might not always appear if you resize the window height .

Comment: Do the lines come and go if you zoom in and out. If so it's not necessarily 1 CSS pixel you are seeing but one screen pixel. As @G-Cyrillus has noted there can be edge effects - a sort of rounding error when the system tries to map a part CSS pixel to the (several) screen pixels that make up one CSS pixels on high def screens.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus the issue is still present when using  `display: grid `. `display: flex` is probably not the problem.

Comment: @AHaworth Zoom doesn't make any differece. But when I am scrolling the effect is sometimes more present.

Comment: @DanWiedenhoever about grid, it was just a comment to build your layout more efficiently, it had nothing to do with that gap appearing. You may hide that gap with a box-shadow to fill it if that happens: `.scrollWrapper > * {box-shadow:0 1px white;}` , then you don't care how your browser will manage heights of your divs at screen. ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus with `box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff;` it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with `box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px white;`:

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: black;
}

.scrollWrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.scrollWrapper > * {
    background-color: white;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%; 
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollWrapper">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Special thanks to @G-Cyrillus.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).